# Numerical Approximation: Integral of Exponential to an Exponential power

Tags: definite-integrals, numerical-methods, exponential-function

I am trying to solve a self-consistent equation for the variable $S$.

$$
\mathbf{S} = \int_0^t C_1 \mathbf{S} e^{-C_2 a-C_3\cdot\mathbf{S}\cdot e^{-C_4 a}} da \\
%
1 = \int_0^t C_1 e^{-C_2 a-C_3\cdot\mathbf{S}\cdot e^{-C_4 a}} da
$$

I would input values of $C_1, C_2, C_3$ and $C_4$ and I am interested in finding the $\mathbf{S}\neq 0$ that satisfies the above equation.

Things I have tried:

I am thinking numerical approximation but I am unfamiliar with the methods used and not sure what to read up on. Perhaps Runge-Kutta or Eulers method? Would appreciate any tips.

I attempted Bisection Method using a Matlab code, trying to solve for the zero of $\int_0^t C_1 e^{-C_2 a-C_3\cdot\mathbf{S}\cdot e^{-C_4 a}} da-1$ but it was giving me an error (I think because of the integral.)
Here is the bisection code:

```
% Clearing Screen
clc

% Setting x as symbolic variable
syms x;

% Input Section
y = input('Enter non-linear equations: ');
a = input('Enter first guess: ');
b = input('Enter second guess: ');
e = input('Tolerable error: ');

% Finding Functional Value
fa = eval(subs(y,x,a));
fb = eval(subs(y,x,b));

% Implementing Bisection Method
if fa*fb > 0 
    disp('Given initial values do not bracket the root.');
else
    c = (a+b)/2;
    fc = eval(subs(y,x,c));
    fprintf('\n\na\t\t\tb\t\t\tc\t\t\tf(c)\n');
    while abs(fc)>e
        fprintf('%f\t%f\t%f\t%f\n',a,b,c,fc);
        if fa*fc< 0
            b =c;
        else
            a =c;
        end
        c = (a+b)/2;
        fc = eval(subs(y,x,c));
    end
    fprintf('\nRoot is: %f\n', c);
end
```

In case it is of interest:
I am vaguely familiar with python, Matlab, C++. More familiar with Mathematica.

Comment: Just to clarify, $S = S(t)$, right? Or is $t$  also given?

Comment: @PierreCarre that’s correct $S=S(t)$

Comment: So just to be explicit it appears you're trying to find $S(t)$ where
$$1 = \int_0^t\, C_1 \exp\bigl( -C_2 a - C_3 S(t) e^{-C_4 a}\bigr)\, da$$ right?

Comment: yes that is the $S(t)$ I would like to compute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have that $S(0)=0$ and, for $t>0$, your integral equation is of the form
$$
\int_0^t f(a) e^{S(t) g(a)} da = 1. 
$$

This can be numerically solved using a numerical quadrature. Suppose that you restrict yourself to a uniform mesh $t_i = i h$, and use the same mesh for the numerical quadrature. You then have
$$
\sum_{j=0}^i \omega_j^{(i)}f(t_j)e^{S_j g(t_j)}=1
$$

solving with respect to $S_i$, you get
$$
\omega_i^{(i)}f(t_i)e^{S_i g(t_i)} =1-\sum_{j<i} \omega_j^{(i)}f(t_j)e^{S_j g(t_j)} 
$$

$$
e^{S_i g(t_i)} = \dfrac{1-\sum_{j<i} \omega_j^{(i)}f(t_j)e^{S_j g(t_j)}}{\omega_i^{(i)}f(t_i)}
$$

$$
S_i = \frac{1}{g(t_i)}\log \left(\dfrac{1-\sum_{j<i} \omega_j^{(i)}f(t_j)e^{S_j g(t_j)}}{\omega_i^{(i)}f(t_i)}\right)
$$

This last recurrence equation approximates the values of $s(t)$ on the mesh. Now, you just need to choose a numerical quadrature, like the trapezoidal rule, and properly compute the weights $\omega_j^{(i)}$.

Answer (score 0):

Just an observation, too much for a comment.

It seems the behavior at $t=0+$ will take a delicate bit of analysis: The left hand side of the equation, the constant $1$, will have to be "balanced" on the right hand side by an integrand that is, or becomes, singular in order for $\lim_{t\rightarrow 0+} \int_0^t$ to keep up, so to speak. A back of the envelope estimate seems to say that for small $t$, $S(t) = C_3^{-1}\log(C_1t) + O(t\log t)$. If nothing else this means any quadrature you end up doing ought to account for this sort of singularity in $S$.